# Deadbolt integration with silhouette

Tags: scala, playframework, deadbolt, silhouette

I am trying to use silhouette for authentication and deadbolt-2 for authorization.

I can't find any resources on how to do that.

Any ideas on how to combine both in one action?

And on how to implement the deadbolt2 getSubject with silhouette identity?

```
override def getSubject[A](request: AuthenticatedRequest[A]): Future[Option[Subject]] = {
    // e.g. request.session.get("user")
    Future(Some(new User("steve")))
 }
```